# Multiline Bootstrap-Select with height: auto

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using [Bootstrap-Select with Multiple select boxes](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/#multiple-select-boxes)  and

```
white-space: normal;
height: auto
```

so it becomes multiline, but `height: auto` grows up the box with (for my opinion) too much space on the bottom (marked with the red line)

Is there any chance to remove it?

[image: Selectpicker with auto height]

Snippet:

```css
select[multiple],
select[size] {
  height: auto;
}
select,
textarea {
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  line-height: inherit;
}
select {
  text-transform: none;
}
button,
input,
optgroup,
select,
textarea {
  color: inherit;
  font: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.input-group {
  border-collapse: separate;
}
.bootstrap-select .btn {
  /* enables multiline on selectpicker */
  white-space: normal !important;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.1/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-group">
    <select multiple="multiple" title="colors" class="selectpicker" name="article[color][]" id="article_color" style="display: none;">
      <option data-value="green" data-content="<i class='fa fa-question-circle-o'></i> Green" value="green">green</option>
      <option data-value="dark green blue yellow" data-content="<i class='fa fa-question-circle-o'></i> Dark Green Blue Yellow" value="dark green blue yellow">dark green blue yellow</option>
      <option data-value="stripes red orange" data-content="<i class='fa fa-question-circle-o'></i> Stripes Red Orange" value="stripes red orange">stripes red orange</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You simply need to move your `white-space` rule to the `.filter-option` class because this is where the plugin updates the selected values.

If you open up **DevTools** and watch `<span class="filter-option pull-left">`, you'll see it update.

**CSS**

```
.bootstrap-select .filter-option { white-space: normal; }
```

**Working Example:**

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}
form {
  max-width: 250px;
  margin: auto;
}
/*USE THE BELOW RULE */

.bootstrap-select .filter-option {
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.1/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <select multiple="multiple" title="colors" class="selectpicker" name="article[color][]" id="article_color" style="display: none;">
        <option data-value="green" data-content="<i class='fa fa-question-circle-o'></i> Green" value="green">green</option>
        <option data-value="dark green blue yellow" data-content="<i class='fa fa-question-circle-o'></i> Dark Green Blue Yellow" value="dark green blue yellow">dark green blue yellow</option>
        <option data-value="stripes red orange" data-content="<i class='fa fa-question-circle-o'></i> Stripes Red Orange" value="stripes red orange">stripes red orange</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

I hope it works

Add this style

```
.bootstrap-select.btn-group .dropdown-toggle .filter-option {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: left;
    white-space: normal;
    width: 100%;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Remove the following style form your CSS

```
select[multiple], select[size] {
    height: auto;
}
.bootstrap-select .btn {
  /* enables multiline on selectpicker */
  white-space: normal !important;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have one under another try this 
css

```
.selectpicker .bootstrap-select .filter-option {
  white-space: pre-line !important;
}
.selectpicker rule_container .bootstrap-select {
  display: block !important;
}
```

js

```
$(".selectpicker").on("changed.bs.select", function (e, clickedIndex, newValue, oldValue) {
            $('.bootstrap-select .filter-option').text($.trim($('.bootstrap-select .filter-option').text()))
        });
    $(".selectpicker").on("loaded.bs.select", function (e, clickedIndex, newValue, oldValue) {
            $('.filter-option').text($.trim($('.rule_container .bootstrap-select .filter-option').text()))
        });
```